# Visual force webpage for classified ads within the company?

Tags: visualforce, lightning, visual-workflow, landing-page

Our company has old furniture, desks, computers etc...That they auction off but before that, they are trying to recycle them and give departments opportunity to see if they are interested. We tried our company Intranet web site but found it too slow for updates. We looked at Sharepoint Web and don't see any Web parts that would suite our needs.

Goal:

> Create a webpage where our inventory team can go in and upload images, descriptions, locations of items that are available (Imagine sort of like Craigslist classified ads). Users would a browse option to upload images and text fields to input dates, descriptions, titles, etc..and other departments can only view these and not make edits.

Can this be achieved either through lighting or Visualforce page in Salesforce?

Similar to something like below:

[image]

Comment: Yes, you could build this in Salesforce quite easily. You barely need any Visualforce or Lightning at all; just set up a custom object with the fields you need, add the Files related list, etc. If you really want to do this in code, you have even more options available, as you can literally build anything you want.

Comment: What about image uploads? They want the option to add minimum 5 images for each item I updated the question with an image of what we were thinking

Comment: Yes, you certainly can. This would be a rather trivial form to build, a few hours to a few days worth of work.

Comment: In fact, we wrote an entire internal tool to allow Sales to help customers find the RVs of their dreams in just a few clicks, driven completely with Salesforce data and files.

Comment: @sfdcfox, Wow sounds awesome! If you can guide on where to find these that would be great! We just need a quick reference template if that's possible.

Comment: There are a number of reference applications in the [Sample Gallery](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/sample-gallery). These may be more complicated than you need.

Comment: I highly recommend against building anything in Visualforce.

Comment: @adrianLarson. Why's that?

Comment: It's ancient technology that isn't really supported moving forward. Salesforce is putting all their UI eggs in the LWC basket.

Comment: Understood. Thank you sir!